# How to print Persian and Arabic (utf-8) characters in Java console?

Tags: java, utf-8, console, persian

I want to use Persian characters to show user the letters in Persian; but I just have received question mark instead of Persian characters. How can I use these characters in Java console?
(I use eclipse-Kepler)

Comment: We have no idea which console you're using - what operating system are you working on, to start with?

Comment: look at this pic. [link](http://upload7.ir/images/75637795670383288388.png)

Comment: Well that doesn't really answer the question, but my guess is that that's the Eclipse console - is it?

Comment: yes. I've told u in my question-last sentence that I use eclipse. my problem is that question marks. they must be persian characters.

Comment: Ah, you edited your question to indicate that, by the looks of it. (It's still not clear just from the question that it's the *Eclipse console* that you were interested in, rather than just that you were building the code with Eclipse.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the eclipse console it should by default support UTF8 (mine does). If it doesn't here is a [link](http://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/) with pictures describing how to change console output encoding. Works fine with the arabic letter phe:

```
String s = "\u0641";
System.out.println(s);
```

Out

```
ف
```

Comment: @AlirezaOmidi: Okay, so for the sake of posterity - did it work when you used that code, or did it work because you changed your console output encoding?

Comment: Yes would be nice to know as well, mine was UTF8 by default and I can never remember having changed it.

Comment: it worked when I changed my console output encoding to utf-8.